# How to move a PersistentVolume from one zone to another zone?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-pvc, persistent-volume-claims

I have a k8s cluster with machines on two different zones. Originally, I have a StatefulSet with PersistentVolumeClaim, and the Pod & PersistentVolume are on zone #1. Now I want the pod to run one zone #2, so I have to move the PersistentVolume to the zone #2 as well.

How can I do so? I know in the different nodes of the *same* zone things are quite simple - the pod will auto bring the PersistentVolume with it. But I do not know what to do across zones.

Thanks very much for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is example on `GKE`, however other cloud providers should have similar options but with different zone names.

You can do it by [Regional Persistent Disks](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/regional-pd#dynamic-provisioning) with specified [StorageClass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/). Depends on your needs you can use:

- **Dynamic Provisioning**

> To enable dynamic provisioning of regional persistent disks, create a `StorageClass` with the `replication-type` parameter, and specify `zone` constraints in `allowedTopologies`.

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: regionalpd-storageclass
provisioner: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
  replication-type: regional-pd
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
allowedTopologies:
- matchLabelExpressions:
  - key: topology.gke.io/zone
    values:
    - europe-west1-b
    - europe-west1-c
```

Above example describes a StorageClass named regionalpd-storageclass that uses standard persistent disks and that replicates data to the europe-west1-b and europe-west1-c zones

- **Manual Provisioning**

```
gcloud compute disks create \
 gce-disk-1 \
   --size 500Gi \
   --region europe-west1 \
   --replica-zones europe-west1-b,europe-west1-c
```

If you would like to create [Persistent Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes) in specific zone you can specify it in `storageClass` like in this example:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: PV-us-central-1a
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
  zone: us-central1-a
```

To use specific `StorageClass` in `PersistentVolume` or `PersistentVolumeClaim` you have to use `storageClassName`.

Below example with `volumeClaimTemplates` and `storageClassName`

```
  `volumeClaimTemplates`:
  - metadata:
      name: www
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "my-storage-class"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

Regarding moving PV to different zone, you can use [Volume Snapshots](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volume-snapshots/) or use 3rd party software like [Velero](https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero). You can find many `migrating PV` tutorials online using `Volume Snapshots` like [Migrating Kubernetes PersistentVolumes across Regions and AZs on AWS](https://hodovi.cc/blog/migrating-kubernetes-persistentvolumes-across-regions-azs-aws/).

**Additional documentation**

- [Using preexisting persistent disks as PersistentVolumes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/preexisting-pd)